# How can I fix TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I just connected mongoDB using mongoose.
But I got error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')`
How can I fix this error?

Here's my code

```
export const dbConnect = async () => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGO_URI);
  const db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', function () {
    console.log('db connection failed!');
  });
  db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('db connected!');
  });
};
```

And I am using mongoose version 6.5.3, next version 12.2.5

Comment: Your issue is very likely not caused in the code that you're showing. Can you at least add the full stack trace of the error to your question?

Answer (score 1):

If the error appears in the browser, it means that you are trying to use Mongoose in your **client side** code.

In fact, somewhere in its code, Mongoose checks for the version of the node installation it's using.

Being ran in the browser, there is no such thing as `process.versions.node`, hence the error.

Mongoose is packed in the final client bundle, hence the error comes from there and it doesn't say much about where you have the wrong `import`/`require` in your code.

One strategy is to search for `"mongoose"` (including the double quotes) in your code, and remove the `import`/`require` from all the files that are meant to be run in the client.

Comment: Any idea how to trace this? The error comes with not much tracing info

Comment: I have added some info to the answer on how to trace the error

Answer (score 0):

What is value of process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGO_URI

Format should be like

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');

Comment: My URI is "mongodb+srv://username:password@serverURI". I got the URI in mongodb homepage. And I connected db successfully in other project using same URI, So I think the URI is correct..

Comment: You need to change ad above remove +srv

Comment: Like you said, I removed +src from URI. But the same error occurs.

Comment: add port and database

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem will be in the connect function. The URI you give in might be wrong. Try logging it our before the function, to make sure it's a correct uri.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/

Here you can find the correct connection string format.

Comment: My URI is mongodb+srv://${name}:${password}@${serverURI}, I got the URI in mongodb homepage. And I connected db successfully in other project using same URI, So I think the URI is correct.

Comment: I found a post about a same issue, maybe it will help:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11558

"Actually it was my bad, the ref was referencing the schema instead of the model." - that was the solution in that post.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Use a dynamic import. instead of:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const connectDb = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect('your-connection-string', {  });
  } catch (error) {
    // exit process with failure
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

Try:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
// import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const connectDb = async () => {
  try {
    // Dynamically load mongoose
    const mongoose = (await import('mongoose')).default;

    await mongoose.connect('your-connection-string', {  });
  } catch (error) {
    // exit process with failure
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

See the docs here: [Dynamic Imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-external-libraries)

Why does this work?

Luca was correct to say the following:

> If the error appears in the browser, it means that you are trying to
> use Mongoose in your client side code.
>
> In fact, somewhere in its code, Mongoose checks for the version of the
> node installation it's using.

To expand on that, `node.js` is not available on the client side of a next.js project, but it is available where server-side code runs such as `getServerSideProps` or `/pages/api`. I assume you only want to use this function inside the `/pages/api` folder and in that case it should work just fine.

Comment: In my case I made sure to not import any files using mongoose on the front end. I had some type definitions in a file that was using mongoose, and had them imported by front end code. Moving the type definitions to a file that did not include mongoose imports fixed it for me.